# how do I set input from user to the value of an input?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate the area of a triangle but I'm finding it hard to get input from user. I gave the input an id and set the value to the innerhtml of the input but it's giving me a default value of 1.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Area Of A Triangle</title>

<style type="text/css">


p{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Calculate The Area Of A Triangle</h2>

<p>Enter The Values</p>

<p><input id="firstside"  type="text" /></p>
<p><input id="secondside" type="text" /></p>
<p><input id="thirdside" type="text" /></p>

<button id="solve">Submit</button>

<p>Answer Is : <span id="answer"></span></p>


<script type="text/javascript" >

var a; var b; var c; var s; var area;

a= document.getElementById("firstside").value==document.getElementById("firstside").innerHTML;
b= document.getElementById("secondside").value==document.getElementById("secondside").innerHTML;
c= document.getElementById("thirdside").value==document.getElementById("thirdside").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("solve").onclick=function() {

s = (a+b+c);

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=s;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your code please, so that we do not need to write it from scratch, we will also see what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the `innerHTML` property, you serialize all the child nodes of the element to HTML and then get that as a string. Setting `innerHTML` does the same thing in reverse.

An input element doesn't (and can't) have any child nodes (`<input>foo</input>`) is invalid HTML).

Its current value is reflected through its `value` property.

Comment: How do i change its value property

Comment: @Hodre — The same what that you change its `innerHTML` property … just with a different word where you currently have `innerHTML`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is Jsbin I've created for you. I hope you would like it

https://jsbin.com/futotexeci/edit?html,output

```
<div class='col-lg-4'>
Base <input type="number" min='0' id='base' class='form-control' />
<hr>
Altitude <input type="number" min='0' id='altitude' class='form-control' />
<hr>
Area <input type="number" min='0' id='area' class='form-control' disabled />
<hr>
<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='findArea()'>Calculate</button>
```

JS

```
function findArea(){
   var base = $('#base').val();
   var altitude = $('#altitude').val();
   var area = 1/2 * base * altitude;
   $('#area').val(area);
}
```

Stay happy and do some effort :)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: But created my own jsbin .. I think I need to add some code instead